# Secure webApplication

Tags: asp.net

I am building an application(asp.net) with online payment so i want to make these payment page SSL enable. How can i do that..
Help me..

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)

Answer (score 1):

Create class similar to

```
public class SecurePage : Page
{
    protected override void OnInit( EventArgs e )
    {
        //retrieve appsettings value. set to false for localhost or dev environment
        var sslRequired = bool.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Security-SSL-Required"] ?? "true");
        var currentUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;

        if (!currentUrl.Scheme.Equals(Uri.UriSchemeHttps, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && sslRequired)
        {
            //build the secure uri 
            var secureUrlBuilder = new UriBuilder(currentUrl);
            secureUrlBuilder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
            //use the default port.  
            secureUrlBuilder.Port = -1;
            //redirect and end the response. 
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(secureUrlBuilder.Uri.ToString());
        }

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

Then for pages that require SSL inherit from this base class:

```
public class Login : SecurePage
{
    protected void Page_Load
        (
        object sender,
        EventArgs e )
    {
    }
}
```